# How do I make changes to a "live database"?

Tags: oracle, insert-update, alter-table, live-update

I have already created a vehicle_unit table

```
 CREATE TABLE vehicle_unit (
 garage_code NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,
 vunit_id  NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,
 vunit_purchase_price NUMERIC(7,2),
 vunit_exhibition_flag CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 vehicle_insurance_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 vunit_rego VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
);
```

And inserted some values in them:

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_unit(vunit_purchase_price,vunit_exhibition_flag,vehicle_insurance_id,vunit_rego,vunit_id, garage_code)
SELECT 50000.00, 'R', 'sports-ute-449-12b', 'RD3161',garage_count_vehicles, garage_code
FROM garage
WHERE garage_email='caulfield@rdbms.example.com';
```

If I want to add a NON NULL column called condition_flag how do I change this live database? Do I use alter table?But how do I insert this new value?

EDIT: I tried 'Alter table" but I got an error saying table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column.

Comment: You just use an `ALTER` statement [like this](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-alter-table-add-column/). Then you can use an UPDATE statement to update existing records with values for this new column and also change your existing INSERT statement for new rows to have values with this new column.

Comment: I've tried alter table but I got table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column. And I really don't think I should be dropping the whole table and recreating it?

Comment: A good way around this to give the column a default value so it won't be empty upon alter. Like `alter table yourtable add yournewcol int default 1 not null;`  Then on your `UPDATE` you can set that value to whatever you like in your existing records. Alternatively you can add without the `NOT NULL` constraint, run your UPDATE to set  a value and then ALTER once again to add the constraint.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `CHAR`. Use the standard string type, which is `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `ALTER ... NOT NULL` statement, update all existing records to have a value (if they already don't). Then issue your `ALTER ... NOT NULL`, or as already recommended by JNevill, also add a `DEFAULT` clause as well (that will save you from modifying code that may not be providing values during `INSERT`s).